# Is it possible to access MS Teams Team member tags via PowerShell or other means?

Tags: microsoft-office-365, user-accounts, microsoft-teams

I was thinking of using Tags assigned to Users in a MS Teams (on Office365) Team for some reporting related things and query them in some PowerShell scripts. Is there a way to get this information?

I was thinking something along the lines of the `Get-TeamUser` command. But I can't really find any PowerShell commands that are able to do that in any way.

If there isn't through PowerShell modules then maybe there's some other obscure way of getting that information? Maybe through Microsoft Graph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use Graph API for this.
Graph API is accessible from many environments, including PowerShell.
Check [**teamworktags** resource type](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/teamworktag?view=graph-rest-beta) in Graph API.

You would have to browse all teams and gather tags members from all of them, since tags are not something global, but team-specific. This means tags can have save names but completely different members.

Comment: I was not able to find that on my own. Thank you for the pointer.